# Test iAds won't load

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, iad

I've been scratching my head about this for a couple of days. I can't get iAds to show up in the simulator (or real hardware).

1. I filled out all the contract information on iTunes Connect
2. Created a development provisioning profile for the app
3. Linked the iAd framework and imported it at the top of the ViewController's swift file
4. Made the ViewController a subclass of ADBannerViewDelegate
5. implemented 3 methods for the delegate (see below)

I can't figure out why the test ads aren't loading. Has anybody else had this problem? As I understand it you no longer have to register each app individually for iAds through iTunes Connect anymore.

I'll include my code below for reference, though I have a suspicion that the problem is somewhere in the setup.

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class AdViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

var bannerView = ADBannerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

    bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.height-50, self.view.frame.width, 50)
    view.addSubview(bannerView)

    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.hidden = true

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.bannerView.hidden = false
    println("bannerView unhidden")
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    bannerView.hidden = true
    println("bannerView hidden")
}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return willLeave
}
}
```

Edit: 
This morning I tried downloading and running some iAd demos from gitHub just to see if I could get them to work, but to no avail. I assume the code is correct, so something must be wrong elsewhere. https://github.com/sarchak/iAds

Comment: Once you set `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` you do not need the bannerView object delegate etc. All is set automatically. When a banner is available, your view controller will be resized with height minus the banner height, and auto layout will be triggered. This way the banner is always presented at the bottom. Check if you put the correct `ADViewController` class in your storyboard. Since you manually add the banner view, isn't your `ADBannerView` embedded in a tab view controller? Maybe your banner is under the tabs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't realize the banner would be added automatically and auto layout would kick. That was very helpful. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have solved the problem.

I tried downloading this sample project and running it, but that didn't work either. https://github.com/ashishkakkad8/iAdBannerExample

Does it work for you?

Comment: Haven't tried, but starting a new project, adding iAd framework and `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`  in  viewDidLoad, just works for me. In a project of mine I used a different approach since I needed to present the ads at the top. I had a bannerView as a singleton used by the various ViewController. Are you a registered (paid) developer? I don't know if it is mandatory in order to receive the development test banners.

Comment: I just tried creating a new project, adding the iAd framework and import statement, and then added `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` in `viewDidLoad`, but with no luck. I am enrolled as a paid developer. I'm really stumped.

Comment: I don't know why, but it just started working on my iPhone. It still doesn't work in the simulator, but at least I'm making some progress now.

Comment: Just to remind you that on your iPhone you can tweak iAd settings under _Settings_ -> _Developer_. If you use a custom placement of the bannerView, it might be useful to turn on _Highlight Clipped Banners_. This way you can visually verify that your layout doesn't cover parts of the ad. Since the ads works on your iPhone, probably seeing them on the simulator is just a metter of time. When you use the automatic banner config `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` you don't see the simulated failed banner requests.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, very helpful. Yeah, I'm not sure what's going on in the simulator, but I'm not going to fret about it too much because I can test now. You're exactly right, the didFailToReceiveAdWithError method never gets called in the simulator, but it does periodically when running on a phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not recommend to manually set the size of an ad view.
use `init()` method and then adjust the frame doesn't make any sense

you should initialize your banner view like this:

`let bannerView = ADBannerView(adType:ADAdType.Banner)`

and then immediately set its delegate and add it to the root view