# iAd not working in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I am having a problem with my code. I am trying to programmatically add an iAd to my view in Xcode. There are a few times when it randomly works, and I run it again without changing any code, and it doesn't work any more. During those few times it randomly works, when I switch to a different view and then back to the one the iAd is in, the iAd is just an empty iAd frame, not showing the animation it should be. It is simply not loading the iAd. Please Help! Code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {
//variables*******************************************
var adBannerView = ADBannerView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    loadAds()
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//iAd**************************************************

func loadAds()
{
    adBannerView = ADBannerView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
    adBannerView.center = CGPoint(x: adBannerView.center.x, y: view.bounds.size.height - adBannerView.frame.size.height / 2 - 50)
    adBannerView.delegate = self
    adBannerView.hidden = true
    view.addSubview(adBannerView)
}

func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!)
{

    println("sort of working1")

}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!)
{

    adBannerView.hidden = false
    println("sort of working2")

}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!)
{


    println("sort of working3")

}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool
{

    println("sort of working4")
    return true 
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!)
{
    adBannerView.hidden = true
    println("error1")
}

}
```

UPDATE 1/28/15:
Somehow, the iAds work now without changing the code, but I am experiencing another problem. After I leave the view that the iAd is in, it turns into a blank white frame with the small iAd logo in the bottom corner of the frame. Also, another large problem is that it darkens the tab bar for the view with the iAd.

Comment: see my answer here:  
    [Test iAds won't load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995945/test-iads-wont-load/28026491#28026491)

Comment: It didn't work. I believe I already do what the link says to do in the loadAds() function. The tab bar is darker than it is supposed to be (compared to view without ad), and when I switch views the iAd turns into a blank frame. @Carrl

Comment: Also, when I am in the view with the ad, it outputs 
"sort of working1
sort of working2"
but it outputs "error1" when I switch views, and go back to the view with the ad.

Answer (score 0):

Not even the println's are working? the iAds are not always displayed, depends of the connectivity to the iAd servers, that's the reason why you should implement the didFailToReceiveAdWithError and hide the banner, in case of no information is comming from the server due to some problem.

Comment: The println's are working. When I try to do it, it returns "working 1" and "working 2", and when I switch views, it gives me "error1"

Comment: Also, it darkens the tab bar.

Comment: In didFailToReceiveAdWithError *remove* the hidden and try doing this: adBannerView.alpha = 0.0   .... and in bannerViewDidLoadAd *remove* the hidden and replace it with adBannerView.alpha = 10.0   ...Alsso temove the hidden in the loadAds() function, let's the code I just told you do the job. hope this helps

Comment: It still makes the tab bar darker than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the automatic iAd presentation you don't need to do anything else after `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`. Your view controller will automatically shrink and auto layout will be triggered when an iAd is available. The iAd will be presented at the bottom.

Thus your sample code can just be:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
}
```

If you need a different behaviour here is a simple [iAd example](https://github.com/perlfly/iAdExample). It uses a singleton `ADBannerView` and can present it at the top of the view.
Anyway consider that the proper way to manually instantiate an `ADBannerView` is: `ADBannerView(adType: ADAdType.Banner)`

Comment: I tried the tutorial, and I got error: Use of unresolved identifier 'moveADBannerToViewController' . I put Global_iAd into my application.

Comment: Have you tried the solution above? It should just work. The example I referred to is needed only in case you need a different behaviour. In case you opt out of the automatic banner, you should not set `self.canDisplayBannerAds` to true. It is false by default.

Comment: I tried what you said, and it doesn't call bannerViewWillLoadAd or bannerViewDidLoadAd. Also, the bottom bar is still darkened when the iAd is loaded

Comment: If you use the automatic solution, you do not need anything to be the banner delegate. Anyway, AFAIK, `bannerViewWillLoadAd` is called just one time. The first time the banner _will go out to load an ad_. If you need to have an explicit delegate, then you do not hate to use `self.canDisplayBannerAds`. Use `bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!)` and `bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!)` to show / hide the banner